# Normalizing data based on mean

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, normalize

I am working on time-series and normalizing data using the following code:

```
df['Norm'] = df['Close'] - df['Close'].rolling(20).mean()
df['Norm'] = ((df['Norm'] - df['Norm'].min()) / (df['Norm'].max() - df['Norm'].min())) * 100
```

I have multiplied it with 100 so i want data between 0-100. After normalization, I'm plotting the data adding a 20 moving average

```
plt.plot(df['Norm'])
plt.plot(df['Norm'].rolling(20).mean())
plt.axhline(0)
plt.axhline(100)
```

Now what I'm wondering if there's a way to normalize final data based on mean? What i am trying to do is, make the mean value equal to 50 and remove mean from the plot.

Answer (score 0):

What about just subtracting the original mean and summing 50?

```
df['Norm'] = (df['Close'] - df['Close'].mean()) + 50
```

Comment: This is what i have tried. Actually my qestion is missing that part. What I'm trying to do is normalize the data after that. Let me update my question